# Unable to translate image using scipy.ndimage.interpolation.affine_transform

Tags: python, scipy, medical

I have got an image that I would like to translate. I am trying to use scipy's affine transformation function. When I try to use the function, I get an error saying '**affine matrix has wrong number of rows**. I've tried googling, but haven't had any luck. Any help debugging this would be really helpful.

```
    import numpy as np
    import scipy.ndimage as nd

    translation_matrix = [[1,0,0],
                          [0,1,0],
                         [tx,ty,1]] 
    output = nd.interpolation.affine_transform(input_image,translation_matrix,order=3,mode='nearest')
```

I get an error here.

EDIT: More details regarding my problem. I have certain slices in my MR image that has tumours. I know which slices contain the tumours and which do not. The tumours need to be centered for further analysis. So, the solution that I have hit upon is to calculate the centroid coordinates of the tumour in a particular slice. Then make the centroid coordinate as the centre of the new image. I need to do this for all the slices which have tumours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the following works. Use a linear (not affine) matrix and specify the offset separately:

```
transformed = nd.interpolation.affine_transform(picture,((np.cos(ph), np.sin(ph)), (-np.sin(ph), np.cos(ph))), offset=(4,-2),order=3,mode='nearest')
```

Comment: Sorry, if it sounds silly, but what is ph. The parameters of the rotation matrix fed in a way such that the image is not rotated?

Comment: It's just a parameter to make the matrix look like a proper matrix. It would indeed be a rotation matrix. You can set `ph` at zero if you do not want to rotate or simply pass ((1,0),(0,1)) for the matrix.

Comment: How to vectorize this code for multichannel images? I have slices of MRI and I am doing it slice by slice, but it's far too slow.

Comment: Could you describe your problem in a bit more detail? Are your transformations pure translations? Or also rotations /shearings? Because in the former case this function may be overkill and something cheaper may be tried. Do the offsets / transformations differ for different slices? How do you determine which transformation to apply in the first place?

Comment: I have added an edit to the question that would help you understand the question better

Comment: Ok, that sounds like only shifting to me. How precise does it have to be? Are integer offsets ok? In that case you could just slice your slices. Just make sure to make copies because in-place transformations of that sort are not safe. So you'd do something like stack[z, yoffs:, xoffs:] = stack[z, :-yoffs, :-xoffs].copy(). Or you could use `np.roll` although I seem to remember some one saying it's not the fastest. You'd have to try.

Comment: Thanks for that. Slicing the slices would still give only the slices which have only the tumour slices. I still will have to do slice by slice translation. Or probably, I did not understand the comment.

Comment: Do you need to move the tumour free slices as well? How are their offsets calculated? For example if you have a stack of tumour free slices between two slices with tumours but with different offsets? -- Re the slice-by-slice thing it will create a bit of overhead but since the innermost two dimensions are vectorised it shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: No, I am not doing it for the tumour free slices. I am not using them. Yeah, I'll try your suggestion.